# how to get select sub-query in which another table whole data get in json format

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, database-administration, mysqladministrator, mysql-dependent-subquery

**Table 1**

[image]

**Table 2**

[image]

**I want this kind of output needed in Format**
[image]

+

*My Current Query this*

```
SELECT *, (SELECT id FROM tb1 where id = 1) as data_json FROM `tb5`
```

i want get table tb1 whole data in one column
like that

```
id | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | data_json
 1 |  ab  |  ab  |  uo  | ty   | [{'col1':1, 'col2':'ok', 'col3':'yy'},{'col1':1, 'col2':'ok', 'col3':'yy'}...]
```

how to change logical here tell me

how can get here whole json data from tb5                                                           i don't want use join and specific column mention want whole tb5

help me .....!

Answer (score 0):

we will need these `json` functions to transform your data.

```
select t1.*,
    json_arrayagg(json_object('col1', t2.col1, 'col2', t2.col1, 'col3', t2.col3)) as data_json
from tb5 t1
inner join tb1 t2 on t2.id = t1.id
where t2.id = 1;
```

Comment: i don't want join and json_object () in which i want all table selected i can't declare specific column